# solidity state variables lost after web3 connection reset

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js

I setup an Ethereum 2 node system using geth and implemented a web3 client that talks to the 2 nodes.

what it looks like: Node A, Node B

I have a EthereumClient JS file where I start 2 web3 clients that talk to both nodes A and B as follows:

```
this.A = new this.web3.a.eth.Contract(abiDefinition);
this.B = new this.web3.b.eth.Contract(abiDefinition);
```

I then deploy the contracts (ensured I deploy it on A and reuse the same address to deploy on B as well)

Here's the contract I am using -

```
contract getSchwifty {
  struct myData
  {
    string actualData;
    bool dataFlag;
  }

  mapping(string=>myData) records;

  function addData(string id, string hashData) public {
    if (records[id].dataFlag != true)
    {
        records[id].actualData = hashData;
        records[id].dataFlag = true;
    }
  }

  function getData(string id) external view returns (string) {
        if (records[id].dataFlag == true)
           return records[id].actualData;
        else
           return "NULL";
  }

}
```

Now, I add some data to it using `addData`  and then retrieve it using the `getData` call. It works. No issues.

However, I now restart EthereumClient JS. (from where all these things are done). Basically, the web3 connection to the Ethereum nodes gets restarted.

Now, when I do the same `getData` operation mentioned above, it always returns Null instead of giving the correct data.

So, basically it looks like if the web3 connection to the Ethereum nodes is reset, the solidity member variables are also going away.

Any tips on what the issue could be? Please note that I am not restarting the actual Ethereum nodes itself - just the web3 client that talks to the Ethereum node